# Create Excel File Using jExcel

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I made an excel file using jExcel API, but when I tried to open that file I got error filename.xls:file format is not valid and I can not open this file, here is my Java code

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Giga\\Desktop\\yvela.xls");
    WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);

    WritableSheet wsheet = wb.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);

    int row = 0;

    for (Student student : students) {
        wsheet.addCell(new Label(0, row, student.getName()));
        wsheet.addCell(new Label(1, row, student.getSurname()));
        row++;
    }

    wb.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `wb.write()` before `wb.close()`.

The `write` method finalizes some things and actually writes the data to the file.